# Definition of 'cut out in'

Tags: phrasal-verbs, literature, literary-english

I was reading 'The Hound of the Baskervilles' for the sake of improving my English and have not found the definition of the phrasal verb in bold:

> ‘I don’t know much about the tariff and things of that
>   kind,’ said he; ‘but it seems to me we’ve got a bit off the trail
>   so far as that note is concerned.’
>   ‘On the contrary, I think we are particularly hot upon
>   the trail, Sir Henry. Watson here knows more about my
>   methods than you do, but I fear that even he has not quite
>   grasped the significance of this sentence.’
>   ‘No, I confess that I see no connection.’
>   ‘And yet, my dear Watson, there is so very close a connection that the one is extracted out of the other. ‘You,’ ‘your,’
>   ‘your,’ ‘life,’ ‘reason,’ ‘value,’ ‘keep away,’ ‘from the.’ Don’t
>   you see now whence these words have been taken?’
>   ‘By thunder, you’re right! Well, if that isn’t smart!’ cried
>   Sir Henry.
>   ‘If any possible doubt remained it is settled by the fact
>   that ‘keep away’ and ‘from the’ are **cut out in one piece**.’

I contextually suggest this phrase means '*concentrated in one place/extract*', but what is its dictionary definition? Moreover, is this expression considered old-fashioned or not?

Comment: The dictionary definition of "[in one piece](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/piece?q=in+one+piece)" is fairly straightforward.

Comment: It is witty! ;)

Answer (score 1):

By looking up an online edition of the story I quickly confirmed what I thought must be the explanation.

Sir Henry has received a note made up of words cut from a newspaper (so that the handwriting isn't recognisable). Holmes remembers having seen a recent article with almost all those words in it. The pairs of words *keep away* and *from the* are next to one another in the article, so the person who composed the note was able to cut them out of the newspaper *in one piece*  rather than as separate words.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Kate! I see what you mean, but that's rather a contextual definition of the phrase 'cut out in.' I am just interested in where I can find the authentic definition of this phrase. Anyway, very grateful for your answer! :)

Comment: It is not a single phrase: "cut out" is one phrase , "in one piece"is another. The fact that they appear closely together in the sentence does not imply that "cut out in" is aphrase.